# Any way to add local interceptor (only for one request)

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to add interceptor only specific to one particular request, like transformRespponse?

Doing like so will add global interceptor that will be executed on every request.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
  return { 
    'response': function(response) {
       if (isBad(response)) {
           return $q.reject(rejectionReason(response));
       }
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: if its for one request why you dont handle it inside $http promise?

Comment: suppose I dont have access to it

Answer (score 0):

I think you over engineer the solution. `$http` already return promise with two callbacks

```
$http.get('your_url').then(onSuccess, onError)

function onSuccess (response) {
  if (isBad(response)) {
       return $q.reject(rejectionReason(response));
   }
   // do some magic
}
function onError(response){
  return $q.reject(rejectionReason(response))
}
```

and really the isBad should probably happen on server side and return an http error so it's handled by `onError`

Comment: I don't have access to the promise

Answer (score 0):

you can get request url inside response function

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
  return { 
    'response': function(response) {
       if(response.config.url == '/particular_request_url'){
           //do something
       }
       return response
    }
  };
});
```